# commands after command "dx --dex --output=classes.dex FINAL.jar" are not executing in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

.
   I am trying to create a batch file to avoid a repetitive  tasks,
but the commands after the command `"dx --dex --output=classes.dex FINAL.jar"` which i execute to create a .dex file from .jar file  do not execute. The commands before `"dx --dex --output=classes.dex FINAL.jar"` command executes serially well, this  command also executes successfully , it does not give me any error.
   But after successful execution of this command command prompt exits automatically,and rest commands do not execute.

Following is my AUTO.bat file:

```
del Freedom_Plus_Img_Cust.apk_signed.apk
del classes.dex
dx --dex --output=classes.dex FINAL.jar
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 30000
move /Y XXXX.apk XXXX.zip
7z d XXXX.zip classes.dex
7z a XXXX.zip classes.dex
move /Y XXXX.zip XXXX.apk 
java -jar signapk.jar certificate.pem key.pk8 XXXX.apk

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@ECHO off
set /p pathName=Enter The Value:
@echo %pathName%
```

So please can anyone tell me why this could happen.Any solution to this could appreaciable.
Thanx in advance  .
Note: I am using Windows XP . .

Comment: where it exits? does it print the `%pathname%`

Comment: Not sure if this is your case, but, if `dx` is `dx.bat` or `dx.cmd`, you will need to use `call dx --dex ...` so the called batch file returns control to the caller.

Comment: @ npocmaka it exits exactly after executing "dx --dex --output=classes.dex FINAL.jar" command . It does not print anything , command prompt directly exits.

Comment: @ MC ND Thanx . .Your comment proved to be useful for me . . i used call  as u mentioned  . . and it worked fine for me . . Thanks again . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repeat the right answer from [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) to remove this already answered question from the list of unanswered questions.

Command `dx` is not a command, nor is it a console application. It is another batch file.

A batch file must be executed from within a batch file using command `CALL` or cmd.exe continues batch execution on the other executed batch file without returning back to initial batch file.

For details about command `CALL` execute in a command prompt window `call /?`

This behavior can be verified easily with 2 batch files.

Batch file 1 with name **test1.bat**:

```
@echo off
test2.bat
echo End of test1.bat
pause
```

Batch file 2 with name **test2.bat**:

```
echo End of test2.bat
Pause
```

Execution of **test1.bat** results in output:

```
End of test2.bat
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The lines after start of **test2.bat** are not executed anymore by cmd.exe.

With changing in **test1.bat** the second line to `call test2.bat` the output on execution of **test1.bat** changes to:

```
End of test2.bat
Press any key to continue . . .
End of test1.bat
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Hint: In batch files it is advisable to call other files (EXE, COM, BAT, CMD, ...) always with their file extension. This makes the execution of the batch file a little bit faster as Windows do not need to search for `name.*` in current directory and in all directories of environment variable `PATH` to find the file which should be executed. It is also advisable to call other files with full path if the batch file must not work with paths relative to current working directory to avoid a dependency on directories in `PATH`.